# How to make a object instance of a existing instance of a usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, static, user-controls

How to make a object instance of a existing instance of a usercontrol?

```
public partial class Rfid : UserControl
```

This is how you would do it with an Window?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
MainWindow my = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Current.Windows` is a collection of all the windows that currently exist in your application. You aren't "making" anything. The window is an object. The window instance is an instance of the window. You're pulling a reference to it out of the collection.

`MainWindow my` in your question is a reference to an instance of `MainWindow`.

There is no such collection of all the user controls, or of any controls. You can get the *immediate* child control of the window, but then you have to recursively look through its children, and their children, and so on.

In the XAML where an instance of the user control is being defined, give it an `x:Name` attribute. Then, in the parent, you can refer to it by name.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<local:Rfid 
    x:Name="FooBar"
    MyProperty="Some Value"
    />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

This is just an example, since you didn't say what you wanted to do with it, or where, or why.

```
public void SomeButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FooBar.MyProperty = "Some other value";
}
```

You should really be doing this with MVVM, of course.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make a object instance of a existing instance of a usercontrol?

Like you would create an instance of any other class:

```
Rfid obj = new Rfid();
```

Or in XAML:

```
<local:Rfid />
```

Both create an instance of the `Rfid` (`UserControl`) class at runtime.

> This is how you would do it with an Window?

No. That gets a reference to an already existing instance of the `MainWindow` class that is referenced from the `Application.Current.Windows` collection property. It doesn't construct any new window object.